# clipping an area out of multiple satellite images in QGIS

Tags: qgis, clip

How can I clip the exact same area out of  multiple satellite images ( multiple bands)? I am working on a remote sensing project and only need a certain island but the images show much more.

Answer (score 2):

It might be faster to use GDAL instead of QGIS even for a couple of images but especially if you will need to do clipping frequently for your area. Use the -projwin option

http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html
The order of coordinates [-projwin ulx uly lrx lry] may feel odd at the beginning.

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -co tiled=yes -projwin 10000 50000 20000 40000 satellite_in.tif clipped_out.tif
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said clip. Menu: Raster > Extraction > Clipper. You can clip your raster from an extent or a mask layer (other vector table). You have other clipping methods too if you use the menu Processing > Commander and type clipping.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another potential way. With this code you could write a batch script.

```
 gdalwarp -q -cutline D:/Temp/aoi2.shp -crop_to_cutline -of GTiff C:/temp/satellite_in.tif Z:/temp/satellite_out.tif
```